# How can I find page views for root of web site in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, homepage

Most of our traffic doesn't come to the root of our web site.

But I would like to know just how much does? It seems like an easy thing to do, and an easy thing to search for, but so far I haven't been able to find the solution.

Comment: Can you edit your question and be more precise ? You can check theses dimensions : `page views` or `landing page` or create a new view and set `http://onrealm.org` as the default page, then check for `/` as an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking at the tracking code on the site. The tracking code snippet is not currently configured for GA tracking. It's configured for Google Ads conversions, which also seems to be incorrectly setup via the gtag tracking code snippet.

This is your current tracking code snippet which has the Google Ads entered erroneously as AW-AW-1071954721 instead of AW-1071954721:

```
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: AW-1071954721 -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-AW-1071954721"></script>
<script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); } gtag('js', new Date()); gtag('config', 'AW-AW-1071954721');</script>
```

To track multiple google products with a single tracking code snippet can be done as per the following code example:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID">
```

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
  gtag('config', 'AW-CONVERSION_ID');
</script>
```

More information on this can be found in the gtag.js dev docs
https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/add
eta.. once the GA tracking is setup and working, then you will be able to see the pageviews in the Behaviour > Site Content > All pages report